# Error in C:\Users\rites\Downloads\hw4.asm line 33 column 2: "delay_loop" is not a recognized operator

Tags: delay, mars-simulator

I just started using MARS please help me out.

```
.macro show_key
jal show_key1
.end_macro

    .text
    .globl  main
main:

    la  $s0, 0xFFFF0004
    la  $s1, 0xFFFF0000
    la  $s2, 0xFFFF0008
    la  $s2, 0xFFFF000C
    li      $t3, 0
    li  $t4, 0


read_key:
    lw  $t0, ($s0)
    beqz    $t2, wait_n_go
    nop

process_key:
    sll     $t0, $t0, 1
    sb  $t0, ($s0)
    lbu $t2, ($s1)
    beqz    $t2, next
    nop
        jal show_key1
    show_key
    nop

wait_n_go:
    delay_loop
    j read_key
    nop


exit:   li  $v0,10
    syscall



show_key1:
    li  $v0,35
    move    $a0, $t2
    syscall
    li  $v0,4
    la  $a0, lf
    syscall
    jr $ra


show_key2:
    move    $t4, $t3
    add     $s4, $s3, $t2
    lb  $t3, ($s4)
    sb  $t3, ($s2)
    sb  $t4, 1($s2)
    jr $ra


    .data
```

Comment: Please format your code neatly in the future. I have done it this time. Please [edit] the question. to explain what you have done to try and understand the problem?

Comment: I'm confused. MARS is "a feature used on Microsoft's SQL Server." This looks like assembler code for MIPS? IAC, assembly language, like any computer language, has a number of commands that it understands.  In this case, things like `sll`, `beqz`, `syscall`, etc.  `delay_loop` is not a valid assembler instruction.  It sounds more like a macro (such as the show_key macro declared at the top of the routine). However since it is not an assembler instruction, and is not a macro, the assembler doesn't know what to do with it (ie not a recognized operator).